# I have used the simpleblobdetector method and i have got two blobs. But now i want to find the x and y points of each blob for angle detection

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

```
for (std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>::iterator blobIterator = keypoints.begin(); blobIterator != keypoints.end(); blobIterator++)
{
    std::cout << "size of blob is: " << blobIterator->size << std::endl;
    std::cout << "point is at: " << blobIterator->pt.x << " " << blobIterator->pt.y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please specify what do you mena by x and y points.

Comment: keypoints[i].pt.x and keypoints[i].pt.y. These are the x and y points. Can you help me with specifying the points of individual blobs.

Comment: do you know the answer for this question?

Comment: I mean common.... No one knows answer to this question ? If anyone has answer please reply it fast...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blob detector does not store individual points. Similar questions appeared on OpenCV Q&A

http://answers.opencv.org/question/7540/calculate-blob-angle/

Basically there are two approaches suggested:

1. Find main axes and find angle from pricipal component analysis
2. Just use findCountours on blob drawn in additional image.

Have fun coding!